# Facebook web authorization using HtmlUnit on groovy

Tags: facebook, cookies, groovy, htmlunit

Year ago I wrote simple Java application, which was able to authorize on site via web-form and then do some little staff (like telling me how many new messages i have etc) Fore some reasons i didn't wrote it via Graph API. And this code worked properly for about year.
Today i've discovered some new problem.  When i try to authorize via web form, it just ends with error "Cookies are not enabled on your browser. Please enable cookies in your browser preferences to continue."

Here is the code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
WebClientOptions webClientOptions = webClient.getOptions();
webClientOptions.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClientOptions.setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClientOptions.setCssEnabled(false);
webClientOptions.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

HtmlPage loginPage = wc.getPage('https://www.facebook.com/login.php')
HtmlForm loginForm = loginPage.getElementById('login_form')
def loginField = loginForm.getInputByName('email')
loginField.type(login)
def passwordField = loginForm.getInputByName('pass')
passwordField.type(password)
def loginButton = loginForm.getInputByName("login")
HtmlPage fbPage = loginButton.click()
```

I've tryed some things like getting cookies in Chrome debug mode and inserting them dirctly into CookieManager, but it didn't help.

How can i pass authorization and what kind of problem it can be?

Comment: Facebook does not want you to login using such automated systems, and is actively taking measures against it. If you want to interact with Facebook on behalf of a user – use their API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the only way is to create a facebook app, authorize this app for my user and then login using oauth?

Comment: I've tryed a lot of things and ended with code like this on java. [link](http://pastebin.com/gSvaqpew) - Still no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it was all because of lib incompability. 
I've inspected my traffic and found that all my requests didnt contain any cookie.
Earlier I've updated version of some httpclient libs for another part of my application and finally it created some bad situation: cookies, createn in old-versioned WebClient part didn't have some attrs, that new httpclient libs wanted. So match check via BasicDomainCheck fails.

The answer is to update all libs. Totally my fault.